# Prove that $ \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}$ doesn't exist using epsilon-delta method

Tags: calculus

> Prove that $ \displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}$ doesn't
> exist using epsilon-delta method

My attempt:

Suppose $ \displaystyle L = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}$ exists and is finite

So we apply the definition that is for given $\displaystyle \epsilon >0 \\ \displaystyle \left| \frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2} - L\right| < \epsilon  \ \ \exists \delta > 0 \text{ such that } \displaystyle \| (x,y)-(0,0) \|<\delta \text{ or simply } \sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta $

Now since the limit doesn't exsit I am trying to prove that we can't find such $\delta$

And I am stuck since then, any help would be appreciated thank you.

And also I know we can solve this particular question using $y=mx^3$ completely avoiding epsilon-delta method, but my question is how do we use this using epsilon-delta.

Comment: Write down formal sentence for negation.

Comment: You can **use** what you know about $y=mx^3$, together with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method (assuming you can apply the suggestion of @zkutch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the formal sentence for the existence of a limit
$$\exists L, \forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \delta>0,\forall x,y\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x,y)-L|<\varepsilon\right)$$
respectively, negation is
$$\forall L, \exists \varepsilon >0, \forall \delta>0,\exists x,y\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta \land |f(x,y)-L|\geqslant\varepsilon\right)$$
now let's work and take, for example, $L=1$. For $\forall \delta>0$ we can consider points $y=x$ in $(0,0)$ neighborhood, for which $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{2x^2}<\delta$. Our function become $\frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}=\frac{x^4}{x^6+x^2} =\frac{x^2}{x^4+1} $ and last fraction "tends" to zero, when $\delta$ "tends" to zero. Using this we can make difference between $f$ and $L=1$ more, then, for example, fixed $\varepsilon = \frac12$. We can do it, for example, in following way: consider $\delta_n=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ and choose any sequence with property $0<x_n<\frac1n$. Then we have $\sqrt{2x_n^2}<\delta_n$ and $\frac{x_n^2}{x_n^4+1}< x_n^2<\frac14$ when $n\geqslant 2$ i.e. difference between $f$ and $L=1$ is more then $\varepsilon = \frac12$.

Now need to carry out the proof for the general case when $L\ne 1$. This is where you can apply $y=mx^3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Glad to be helpful.